# How to draw the .NET controls after setting data in properties of specific controls using overrideables?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-4.0, ui-automation

I need to draw controls using the .NET "show" method of Control.

Suppose I have to draw TreeViewControl on a WinForm by providing test data on some click event, but it's not drawing over the parent WinForm.

Here's the code:

```
public class TestTreeView: TreeView
{
    public TestTreeView()
    {

    }
    public override Color BackColor
    {
        set;
        get;
    }

    public override Image BackgroundImage { set; get; }
    public override ImageLayout BackgroundImageLayout { set; get; }
    public BorderStyle BorderStyle { get { return base.BorderStyle; } }
    public bool CheckBoxes { get { return base.CheckBoxes; } }
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams 
    { get { return base.CreateParams; } }
    protected Size DefaultSize { get { return base.DefaultSize; } }
    protected override bool DoubleBuffered { set; get; }
    public TreeViewDrawMode DrawMod { get { return base.DrawMode; } }
    public override Color ForeColor { set; get; }
    .....
    .....
    .....

    ..all other overrideables
    #endregion

    public void Sort()
    {

    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return null;
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {

    }

    public void setPropeties()
    {
        this.BackColor = Color.Black;
        this.BackgroundImage = null;            
        this.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
        this.Text = "Test Control";
    }
    public void Show()
    {
        // I used following line of statement
        base.show();

        // then for the testing sake, also construct test control object and 
        // set some data to if, it also didn't work as well.

        Control oControl = new Control();
        oControl.Text = "Test Control";
        oControl.BackColor = Color.Black;
        oControl.Height = 125;

        oControl.Show();

    }
}
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TestTreeView oTreeView = new TestTreeView();
        oTreeView.setPropeties();
        oTreeView.Show();
    }
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: of course, use `this.Controls.Add(oControl);` in `Show` BUT it is much better to erase all the code -> learn basic principles of OOP and then continue. 'this' .. won't work anyway

Comment: why 'this' won't work? is these all are static methods? simple properties of a class.

Comment: Can you please write donw the exact modified code of above suggested, i.e this.Control.Add(oControl)? where it should be? and by adding in side Controls list, how it will draw this on existing WinForm?

Comment: yo are talking about overall structure of the code? Can you please advice accordingly ?

Comment: ok, let's start from the beginning... why do you want to `draw controls using .NET "show" method`

Comment: long story:-) , actually I am building up .NET automation framework for WinForms. At first , I do need to extract all properties fo each control drawn on any managed process which's running as process, after that these all would be serialized to other process, that pricess would draw all of these controls. but there again custom objects build up e.g TestButton : Button{..}, and TestTreeView : TreeView {...} etc. Then each control gets draw on som test WinForm exactly at that position, which was drawn in the original process, with all those properties which originally extracted.

Comment: When somebody hits these newly replicated created controls, actually the input will be given to original process having these controls, Input will be passed to those controls which were drawn in original process, so by this means, GUI testing will be enabled some how. This is summarized.

Comment: Here I am facing a problem , 
I need to re-draw these test controls, those are actually inherited with their original control classes (e.g TestButton inherited ".NET Button" and TestTreeView inherited ".NET TreeView" class. So whenever show method needs to be called, this newly control having test same data , properties must be drawn., More over I am not understanding how to set the parent control in this manner, say I want to draw above TestTreeView control on the winform.

Comment: You are overriding WndProc without passing the message to the base.Wndproc.  Your control won't work — it's ignoring all of the window messages.

Answer (score 0):

These lines do no really thing:

```
    Control oControl = new Control();
    oControl.Text = "Test Control";
    oControl.BackColor = Color.Black;
    oControl.Height = 125;

    oControl.Show();
```

The `oControl` has no `Parent` (exactly, `Container`), so where will it show? You need to add it to a container (maybe the control you are creating, using `this`)

Comment: yeah this is i done and succeeded with it, but I am having another problem, see my additional comments sir..

Comment: I do not need to build "Control" object by hand, I do need to build up TestButton,TestTreeView etc by hand, which in turns should display exactly .NET respective control by having all those properties, which actually set by client of these classes. as These classes actually taking inheritance with their a tual respective classes (e.g TreeView, TestButton inheriting Button) etc.